# How to do basic parameter passing in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, gdbinit

I have the following defined in my `.gdbinit`  to make it easier to print "the stack" when I want to see it in decimal format:

```
define s
   x/5gd $rsp
end
```

Now I can type in something like:

```
>>> s
0x7fffffffe408: 10  8
0x7fffffffe418: 6   4
0x7fffffffe428: 2
```

By default it will print 5 8-byte values. How can I use an input parameter to use the number I pass instead of 5? For example, something like:

```
define s(d=5)
   x/%sgd $rsp % d
end
```

Also, I'm familiar with python, so as long as I can access the input param, I could use that as well, i.e:

```
def stack():
    return "x/%sgd" % ('5' if not argv[1].isdigit() else argv[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to a `define` command in gdb are accessable as `$arg0`, `$arg1`, etc.  The number of arguments is in `$argc`.  Note that `$arg0` is the first argument (not the command like in C command line arguments.)  So you could write

```
define s
    if $argc == 0
        x/5gd $rsp
    else
        x/$arg0 $rsp
    end
end
```

Comment: great thank you. By the way, it works with `x/$arg0` but not with `x/${arg0}`.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is $argc and $arg0 $arg1 .... .
You can find how to implement User-defined Commands in https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html  .